# Excel VBA - how to efficiently copy multiple cells from one file to another?

Tags: excel, copy, excel-2003, vba

currently, I am struggeling with the following:
I have two Excel files. One files contains a lot of data, the other one is used to evaluate it.
Now I need to efficiently copy data from the source to the target workbook. The source datapattern looks similar to the following:

```
x A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
1 Oct bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
2             75              66 
3 Nov bla bla IMT Frm bla bla IMT Frm
```

Where bla represents uninteresting data, Column A represents the Month (important) and IMT is important data, which is the cause of why I am doing this. Also, Frm means the cell contains a formula, rather than a value and has to be preserved/restored.
Furthermore, the cell formatting of the target file has to be preserved (can be achieved with .PasteSpecial).

The Target Workbook does look exactly the same, omitting the half emty row "2".

Every row has about 10 valuable entries. How would I, most efficiently, be able to copy the data into the second workbook?
Please let me know if there is more information which I could provide.
Thank you for your time!

EDIT: [example screenshot](http://imageshack.us/f/208/excelw.jpg/)
Clarification: The screenshot shows the source sheet. The important information is the one which is selected in the ss. The sheet goes on to the right like this (until BF). I need to copy every sixth entry. The target sheet looks exactly the same (omitting the half empty middle row), except for the needed information which, in the source, is a formula but it needs to be the value in the target.
Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code that will get you going in the right direction:

```
Public Sub CopyValues()

Dim wb_src As Workbook, wb_dst As Workbook
Dim ws_src As Worksheet, ws_dst As Worksheet

Set wb_src = Workbooks.Open("....")
Set wb_dst = Workbooks.Add()

Set ws_src = wb_src.Sheets(1)
Set ws_dst = wb_dst.Sheets(1)

Dim data() As Variant
Dim r_src As Range
Dim r_dst As Range

Set r_src = ws_src.Range("B4").Resize(1000, 100)
Set r_dst = ws_dst.Range("B4").Resize(1000, 100)

data = r_src.Value2
r_dst.Value2 = data

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vFile As Variant

    'Set source workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Open the target workbook
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls", _
        1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
    'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open vFile
    'Set targetworkbook
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy data from a range in the first workbook to another range in the other workbook
    wb2.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:D4").Value = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your help!
the code above however requires me to know the range into which is pasted beforehand. That however, varies depending on the month. I can find the Cell which contains the month and I know the offset. But I would need to somehow iterate through them to get to my target cell wouldn't I?

Comment: does this help you?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx ... you'll have to put in a conditional to check for the month

Comment: thanks again, yes that helps! however, as there is no condition which I can generally apply to filter the needed cells, is there a way of going through e.g. each third cell?

Comment: can you describe in detail what you want to do for each row in the source (step by step) and what you want to do in the target workbook for that row (step by step)?  I'm not understanding what the goal is.  It might help a lot if you can take a screen shot image of the source and make a quick hard copy of the target and insert those images in your questions so I can help.

Comment: sounds like you want to move all data except row 2 in the target, correct?  if that's the case, why not copy the entire range.  Then do the cleanup ONLY in the target once the data is there?  One trick that I use to get quick and easy VBA code is to record a macro and then stop recording, see what the code looks like in the macro and apply it to your custom code.

Comment: in that case, manually delete row 2 with the mouse by clicking while you record and find out what that code is.

Comment: I have added a screenshot and some more information. actually, the two upper rows are required to calculate some data in the thrid row, thus necessary on the source sheet.

Comment: `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open vFile`is shorter and safer

Answer (score -2):

so after some more research, I think I have found an answer.
Please, correct or improve me if my approach is off/wrong/not ideal.
I am using a loop and then just assingin the value... I am wondering, coming from C++, if this is the "shortest" way of doing it? looks like a bloated for loop to me...

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 6 To 55
    targetSheetSal.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i + 1).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(24, i).Value
    i = i + 5
Next i
```

Thank you all for your time, input and advice!

Comment: -1 Do not copy cell by cell. Look at other examples and copy ranges of multiple cells. It is many times faster. Example: `Range("A2").Resize(300,20).Value` returns an array of `300` x `20` values starting from cell `"A2"`. You can assign an array to a range in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is it however possible, to define a range with "gaps" without inputting every individual column (possibly 100+)? as in, every sixth cell? possibly utilising offset() or how could you achieve that?

Comment: Yes you can. One option is to select a range based on a list of cells like `Range("B4:C9,E4:D9")`. Alternatively you can do it in VBA by modyfing the array directly. Post another question with this to get a full answer.